# Angular 9 HttpErrorResponse 'JSON.Parse error' while response is OK

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Why this throws an error?

```
 deleteUser(userId: string) {
    this.dataService.deleteUser(userId).subscribe((response: string) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()
> at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:34968:51)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:412:35)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:72879:33)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:411:40)
> at Zone.runTask (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:180:51)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:493:38)
> at invokeTask (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:1634:18)
> at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js:1671:25)"

The response is plain string value and has status 200.

[image]

[image]

What have I missed?

Comment: Can you post the data being returned from the http request?

Comment: Are you using `JSON.Parse()` in the front-end? If not probably the error stems somewhere in the backend.

Comment: @user2263572 you can see it on the screenshot, in `error` body there property `text`

Comment: @MichaelD no, I am not. how it may be in the back if back returns string and it's all?

Comment: @anatol: I'd be better if you could provide how the back-end in `http://localhost:5001` is implemented. Especially the handling of `/api/data/users/...` end-point.

Comment: @anatol are you sure that's the response and not an error messege generated on the frontend?  I'd double check the "network" tab in your developer console and look for the actual raw response.

Comment: @user2263572 I am sure, absolutely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the deleteUser method in your dataService with the correct responseType (JSON is the default). Also, I'm assuming that's where you use the httpClient.

```
httpClient.get('your_endpoint', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

You are returning text, not JSON.