# How to parse/find parsing error JSON - TypeScript object in Angular/RxJS app?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have and array in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "SupplierID": 1,
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
        "UnitPrice": 18,
        "UnitsInStock": 39,
        "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
        "ReorderLevel": 10,
        "Discontinued": false,
        "Category": {
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "CategoryName": "Beverages",
            "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
        },
        "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20)
    },
...
]
```

I want to create array of objects:

```
export interface IProduct2{
    ProductID: number,
    ProductName: string
}
```

Attempt to get from HTTP file and parse:

```
products2$ = this.http.get<IProduct2[]>(this.product2Url)
.pipe(
  map(products =>
    products.map(product => ({
      ...product,
      searchKey: [product.ProductName]
    } as IProduct2))),
  tap(data => console.log('Products 2: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Display in component:

```
<p>
  {{products2$ | async | json}}
</p>
```

Error: "Server returned code: 200, error message is: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/products/products2.json"

So how to parse it properly into array of objects? How to properly display parsing success/errors, so I can figure out which part of JSON is causing issue? If it's a JSON file should be fine formatted.

Demo application with this issue is here: https://github.com/sam-klok/ang-http-data

Comment: Seems the response is not valid json

Comment: Except for the three dots (which I assume to not be present in the actual file), the JSON appears fine. But you can copy and paste the contents of the file into an online parser like  https://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to find the errors yourself.

Comment: Otherwise, you can set tell HttpClient not to parse the response so you can parse it yourself and catch the error. See answers to [Angular 9 HttpErrorResponse 'JSON.Parse error' while response is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63230566/215552)

Comment: I copied JSON from reputable tutorial.. didn't realized that it does faulty. It have TypeScript code in it... I will post detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is due to

```
"FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20)
```

You can verify using an online JSON parser like http://json.parser.online.fr/

[image]
JSON does not allow that, you should rather specify the date as a string in ISO-8601.

As `new Date(1996, 8, 20).toJSON()` returns `1996-09-19T18:30:00.000Z`, you can replace the above date value as below

```
"FirstOrderedOn": "1996-09-19T18:30:00.000Z"
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/3423750

Comment: Yes. Looks like this JSON was a TypeScript initializer file before.. Incorrect data basically.